# NextJS 13 App Directory. Error when fetching from prisma data

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have this server component that i get the data from prisma. Then, i want to pass the data to component Team so to display my barbers Team, i post you my Team client component    . The problem is that on my server component my barbers are displaying but on Team client component dont. Can you help me? Thanks. Tell me if you want more information. Thanks.[image]

Code of client component:

```
`"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import barber1 from "@/public/h2-team-img-1.jpg";
import barber2 from "@/public/h2-team-img-2.jpg";
import barber3 from "@/public/h2-team-img-3.jpg";
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitter, FaInstagram } from "react-icons/fa";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

interface Barber {
  name: string;
  category: string;
  quote: string;
  social: string;
}

export default function Team({ barbers }) {
  console.log("Barbers: ", barbers);

  const [data, setData] = useState<Barber[]>([]);
  const [isAnimation, setIsAnimation] = useState(false);
  const anim1Ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);
  const anim2Ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);
  const anim3Ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);
  const anim4Ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);
  const anim5Ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);

  const handleIntersection = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const { target, isIntersecting } = entry;

      const id = target.getAttribute("id");
      if (isIntersecting && id === "team") {
        setIsAnimation(true);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const observerOptions = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "100%",
      threshold: 0.5,
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      handleIntersection,
      observerOptions
    );
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".page-observe");

    sections.forEach((section) => {
      observer.observe(section);
    });

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAnimation) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        anim1Ref.current?.classList.add("anim1");
      }, 100);
      setTimeout(() => {
        anim2Ref.current?.classList.add("anim2");
      }, 200);
      setTimeout(() => {
        anim3Ref.current?.classList.add("anim3");
      }, 400);
      setTimeout(() => {
        anim4Ref.current?.classList.add("anim3");
      }, 600);
      setTimeout(() => {
        anim5Ref.current?.classList.add("anim3");
      }, 800);
    }
  }, [isAnimation]);

  return (
    <section id="team" className="relative pt-14 page-observe">
      <div className="justify-center text-center">
        <h1 className="text-5xl font-medium mb-4 opacity-0" ref={anim1Ref}>
          Our Barbers
        </h1>
        <p
          ref={anim2Ref}
          className="text-[rgba(86,86,86,0.8)] text-lg text-center md:pb-0 pb-8 opacity-0"
        >
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at
          porttitor sem. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-1 gap-4 justify-center 1xl:px-40 2xl:px-72 xl:px-10 sm:px-24 px-12 mt-16">
        {barbers.map((barber: Barber, index: number) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="grid justify-center w-full xl:w-[400px] opacity-0"
            ref={
              index === 0
                ? anim3Ref
                : index === 1
                ? anim4Ref
                : index === 2
                ? anim5Ref
                : null
            }
          >
            <div className="relative">
              <Image
                className="w-full object-cover"
                src={
                  index === 0
                    ? barber1
                    : index === 1
                    ? barber2
                    : index === 2
                    ? barber3
                    : ""
                }
                alt="Card Barber"
              />
              <div className="flex justify-center w-full absolute bottom-0 bg-[#b9873f] opacity-90">
                <div className="mb-[0.5px] hover:bg-black transition-colors duration-150 px-1">
                  <Link
                    target="_blank"
                    href={`https://www.instagram.com/${barber.social}/`}
                  >
                    <FaFacebook className="text-2xl text-white rounded-full m-1" />
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-[0.5px] hover:bg-black transition-colors duration-150 px-1">
                  <Link
                    target="_blank"
                    href={`https://www.instagram.com/${barber.social}/`}
                  >
                    <FaTwitter className="text-2xl text-white rounded-full m-1" />
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-[0.5px] hover:bg-black transition-colors duration-150 px-1">
                  <Link
                    target="_blank"
                    href={`https://www.instagram.com/${barber.social}/`}
                  >
                    <FaInstagram className="text-2xl text-white rounded-full m-1" />
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="p-6 text-center w-full">
              <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold">{barber.name}</h3>
              <p className="text-[#b9873f] italic font-normal">
                {barber.category}
              </p>
              <p className="text-gray-700 py-8 mx-auto border-t border-b mt-2">
                {barber.quote}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}`
```

Comment: what do u log here: `console.log("Barbers: ", barbers);` in `Team` component

Comment: @Yilmaz I want to log the barbers from prisma